# Protractor "signing in" || "login" test

Tags: testing, protractor

I have a problem with Protractor. This is my first steps, that is why I can make a really stupid mistake.

So I have conf file:

```
exports.config = {
    framework:       'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs:           ['src/test/webapp/validator/*spec.js'],
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
}
```

and my test:

```
describe('Protractor first sign in test', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.driver.get('http://localhost:3000/#/login');
        browser.waitForAngular();
        //expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + '#/login');
    }, 30000);

    it(function () {
        var user = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username'));
        var password = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password'));
        //var button = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[ng-click="login()"]'));
        var button = element(by.css('[ng-click="login()"]'));

        user.sendKeys('first');
        password.sendKeys('nope');

        expect(user.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('first');
        expect(password.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('nope');

        button.click().then(function (){
            browser.waitForAngular();
            expect(browser.driver.get('http://localhost:3000/#/panel'));
            //expect(authenticationError.toBe(true));
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```

So the browser can load exact adress, and all the elements shows up, but then suddenly test ends with failure without proceeding with sending keys. All the actions is finished in about 1.10sec.

Of course Selenium webdriver-manager is already up.

Maybe someone of you see what is going on, and can give me advice in this matter?

Comment: Can you update the question with details on what error you were seeing and the stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it :) `it()` takes two arguments. 1. String and 2. Function

`it('<<Name of the test>>',callBackFunction())`

You are passing a function as first argument , whereas its expecting a string. 
I would suggest to finish the [tutorial here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) to get started easily on Protractor and take the demo project as base

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should add one and two', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');    
});
```

Comment: I have seen basic tutorial, but i didnt concern on this. I am really embarassed with such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much. I will test that in a second.

Comment: Glad that it worked ! .. All the best for your next steps with protractor